Running a Kafka Connect worker without automatically creating topics
I need to run Kafka connect worker on a new port. The worker configuration is as follows:
bootstrap.servers=some-kafka-server.com:9092

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

group.id='maks-connect-dev'
offset.storage.topic=maks.kafka-connector-offset
config.storage.topic=maks.kafka-connector-config
status.storage.topic=maks.kafka-connector-status

sasl.mechanism=OAUTHBEARER
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.login.callback.handler.class=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler
sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url=https://auth.example.ru/auth/realms/platform/protocol/openid-connect/token
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required \
  clientId="******************" \
  clientSecret="**********************" ;

topic.creation.enable=false
plugin.path=/opt/kafka/connect_plugins
listeners=https://1.1.1.1:8084

despite the option topic.creation.enable=false Kafka connect send CREATE_TOPIC request:
[2024-08-01 12:12:54,868] DEBUG [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-8] Sending CREATE_TOPICS request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=CREATE_TOPICS, apiVersion=7, clientId=adminclient-8, correlationId=820) and timeout 3423 to node 1: CreateTopicsRequestData(topics=[CreatableTopic(name='maks.kafka-connector-offset', numPartitions=25, replicationFactor=3, assignments=[], configs=[CreateableTopicConfig(name='cleanup.policy', value='compact')])], timeoutMs=3423, validateOnly=false) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:521)

and finally crashes with an error:
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Timed out while checking for or creating topic(s) 'maks.kafka-connector-offset'. This could indicate a connectivity issue, unavailable topic partitions, or if this is your first use of the topic it may have taken too long to create.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.TopicAdmin.createOrFindTopics(TopicAdmin.java:423)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.TopicAdmin.createTopics(TopicAdmin.java:332)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaOffsetBackingStore.lambda$createKafkaBasedLog$0(KafkaOffsetBackingStore.java:137)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog.start(KafkaBasedLog.java:170)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaOffsetBackingStore.start(KafkaOffsetBackingStore.java:151)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.start(Worker.java:186)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.startServices(AbstractHerder.java:135)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.run(DistributedHerder.java:320)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to send the call. Call: createTopics


I created these topics in advance
ips-dev1:/opt/kafka # /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server some-kafka-server.com:9092 --command-config /opt/kafka/config/maks-cluster --list
\[2024-08-01 13:42:31,242] WARN [Principal=:8c7a6a20-1426-430d-b748-939157e12401]: Expiring credential expires at Thu Aug 01 13:47:31 MSK 2024, so buffer times of 60 and 300 seconds at the front and back, respectively, cannot be accommodated.  We will refresh at Thu Aug 01 13:46:33 MSK 2024. (org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.internals.expiring.ExpiringCredentialRefreshingLogin)                                                                                 __consumer_offsets
__strimzi-topic-operator-kstreams-topic-store-changelog
__strimzi_store_topic
demo-topic
maks.audit.messages
maks.dealing.commands
maks.dealing.events
maks.dealing.query-get-order-by-id
maks.dealing.query-get-orders
maks.dealing.query-results
maks.kafka-connector-config <<<<<
maks.kafka-connector-offset <<<<<
maks.kafka-connector-status <<<<<
maks.transfer-rates.universal-json
maks.transfer-rates.websocket-event

I also tried adding these options:
allow.auto.create.topics=false
auto.create.topics.enable=false

but the result is the same. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?
